# javac Main.java is not working in cmd

Tags: java

I have 3 class as below:

**First:**

```
package com.coban.menu;

public class Square {

    public static double Perimeter(double x) {
        return 4 * x;
    }

}
```

**Second:**

```
package com.coban.menu;

public class Circle {
    public static final double PI = 3.14;

    public static double Acreage(double x) {
        return PI * x * x;
    }
}
```

**Third:**

```
package com.coban.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

import com.coban.menu.Circle;
import com.coban.menu.Square;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Selection");
        System.out.println("1 - Square perimeter");
        System.out.println("2 - Circle Acreage");

        int x = scan.nextInt();

        switch (x) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Input edge length:");
            float chieuDaiCanh = scan.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Square perimeter: "+Square.Perimeter(chieuDaiCanh));
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Input radius:");
            float banKinh = scan.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Circle Acreage: "+Circle.Acreage(banKinh));
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("M nhap cai lol gi the?");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

The program is working well in IDE.
Why `>javac Main.java` is not working in cmd?

Err1:

```
com.coban.menu pakage does not exist
```

Err2:

```
cannot find a symbol in :
 System.out.println("Square perimeter: "+Square.Perimeter(chieuDaiCanh));
 System.out.println("Circle Acreage: "+Circle.Acreage(banKinh));
```

Somebody help me!

Comment: Please post your project structure, and point out exactly where each of the three `.java` files is being stored.

Comment: it can't find the classes you import. javac is working just fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to compile a single class, that depends on other classes. As long as java has not compiled all the other classes first, your Main.java will fail to compile.

Try compiling the other two classes first or use

```
javac *.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class path, if it's not the default.  And as per the other answer, make sure the classes that your class depends on have been compiled already.

javac -cp  Main.java

Answer (score 0):

From your sources folder in which the `com` folder is visible, first compile the two shapes classes:

```
javac com/coban/menu/Square.java com/coban/menu/Square.java
```

Then compile the `Main` class:

```
javac com/coban/main/Main.java
```

I tested both of the above, and it works.  The class files will, by default, be placed into the same folder where their source files are.  When you want to run your program, just use `java` from the same location:

```
java com/coban/main/Main

Selection
1 - Square perimeter
2 - Circle Acreage
```

Comment: I haven't compiled two shapes classes yet.
Thank you!

Comment: @ĐứcLê Then you can't compile `Main.java`, period.  It depends on those two shape classes.  What I gave you above should work, there are also other ways of doing it, but you need to compile the shape classes _first_.

Comment: Ok, will do it. Thanks!

Comment: @ĐứcLê Can you upvote/mark this answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Generally your IDE will put class files in "bin" folder of the project. To change the default class file path go to
Project -> Properties -> Build Path - Source(Tab) -> Browse.
Where your java files will be in src folder.

Bellow are the steps to compile and run your program through cmd.

1. cd PROJECT_PATH
2. javac -d bin src\com\coban\menu*.java src\com\coban\main*.java (where bin is the folder where your class files are located)
3. cd PROJECT_PATH\bin
4. java com.coban.main.Main (to run the program from command line).

Comment: Thanks! I have one question. If my project has many folder, and I located many java files in each folder. So I will do that every time?
I mean, I will have to run javac command on all folder before running Main?